# Django ValueError The view todo_lists.views.visualisation didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: javascript, python, django, chart.js

everyone. I have views.py here, I want to calculate different status' tasks and output to chart.js pie-chart. I have tried many ways but none of them works. I have an error saying my views def didn't return HttpResponse, can anyone tell me what it is, please? I used template tags in HTML.

Thanks.

**views.py**

```py
def visualisation(request, project_id):

    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)

    counts_data = Todo.objects.annotate(
        to_do_count = Count('id', filter=Q(status='to_do')),
        in_progress_count = Count('id', filter=Q(status='in_progress')),
        done_count = Count('id', filter=Q(status='done'))
        ).order_by('-to_do_count')

    context = {'counts_data', counts_data}
    return render(request, 'todo_lists/progress.html', context)
```

**html**

```
    data: {
        labels: [1,2,3],
        
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',

            data:[{% for todo in counts_data %} {{ todo }}, {% endfor %}],,
            
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
```

Comment: Your view looks good, given the error message you have the template and have imported render. Have you added a print statement to be sure you are actually calling that function? (As opposed to left over function called ```visualizations```? I've made that mistake before, but from the code you've given it's hard to tell.

Comment: @sintribu Yep, you remind me of that, it turned out I have a same function with the same name, tried to do some experiments on my code but forgot to delete it. If u make it an answer Ill accept, cheers bro

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that offer, but it's not a big deal though. Happy to pay my pains forward haha. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a def function that has the same name and did not have return sentence, delete it and the issue is gone. @sintribu cheers